# Android browser sets width to 100% regardless of margin applied to elements (ie blockquotes)

Tags: android, css

My biggest annoyance with browsing websites on my Android browser is reading text with indented blockquotes. Android's webkit implementation (correctly, in my opinion) sets the width on any text element to the browser width.

However, this means that list and blockquote elements which have left margin or padding applied to them hang over the right edge of the visible screen. This makes for annoying reading experience, as the user has to be constantly scrolling right and left to read.

This behavior is visible in just about any site viewed on Android, and my feeling is that this constitutes a bug in the browser.

But my question is: does anyone have a good css solution to preventing this issue? I've tried wrapping all body text in a block-level element with max-width: 100%, but elements with left padding or margin still hang off the edge.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix that by setting the box model for the div/p/li etc. 
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;

Comment: Interesting concept, and I wasn't familiar with the box-sizing property. But it doesn't seem to help on the Android browser. A post at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html says "box-sizing does not work in combination with min- or max-width or -height.", which could be the problem on Android.